# How to pass parameters to the BroadcastReceiver declared in AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `SMSReceiver` declared in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.SMSReceiver"
          android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is disabled by default and I enable it, when needed:

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, SMSReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        component,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

How could I pass some parameter to `SMSReceiver` in this case? I use `SharedPreferences` currently, but it doesn't look good since I don't take care about Activity closure etc.

Comment: I use SharedPreferences currently, but it doesn't look good since I don't take care about Activity closure etc. **Can you please explain why is it bad?**

Comment: If you cannot control the `Intent` received by the `BroadcastReceiver`, you have to rely on local storage, either shared prefs, a file, database etc. I don't see why that would be a bad solution?

Answer (score 1):

> How could I pass some parameter to SMSReceiver in this case?

In the abstract, you send it a broadcast. Just because you *enable* a component does not mean that you *instantiate* a component.

However, since manifest-registered `BroadcastReceivers` do not live past the end of `onReceive()`, I have no idea what you think that passing "some parameter" to such a receiver would accomplish.

Moreover, since `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread, you should not be doing anything significant in the `BroadcastReceiver` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. In one case, depending on SMS text received, I should initiate reply to my main activity (this is done thru `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.REGISTRATION_REPLY_ACTION); LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);`). In another case, I shouldn't do it.

Comment: Btw, as you say `manifest-registered BroadcastReceivers do not live past the end of onReceive()` does it mean that I shouldn't call `setComponentEnabledSetting(..., PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, ...)` there once needed SMS is received?

Comment: @LA_: Then your criteria for that "case" should be in a persistent store, perhaps with an in-memory cache. `SharedPreferences` is not a bad solution. "does it mean that I shouldn't call... once needed SMS is received?" -- how should I know? I didn't write your app. You disable the component when you no longer want its `<intent-filter>` to work. You enable the component when you do want its `<intent-filter>` to work. Despite the method name, you're not enabling/disabling some *instance* of the component, but rather its manifest entry.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way of passing parameters via [ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html).

What I do when a receiver needs configuration is to create a ReceiverParam singleton, and have the receiver 
read it before execution:

```
class SMSReceiverParams {
     private String param1;
     private String param2;

     private static SMSReceiverParams instance;

     public static SMSReceiverParams getInstance() { ... }


    public void setParam1() { .. } 

    public String getParam1() { .. } 

}
```

Now, from my app init code (say an Activity) - perform the configuration:

```
SMSReceiverParams.getInstance().setParam1(...);
SMSReceiverParams.getInstance().setParam2(...);
```

And at receiver end - read the params before onReceive() execution

```
class SMSReceiver {

         void onReceive() {
                 SMSReceiverParams params = SMSReceiverParams.getInstance(); // <--------
                 // and use them
          }
}
```